# Como integrar uma aplicação Web para Chamar uma aplicação Desktop C# biometria

Tags: c#, websocket, integração

Boa tarde,

Preciso fazer a requisição pelo browser (chrome) chamando um windows form c# no mesmo computador, que é uma aplicação de biometria, ambos uso c#.

Tenho ambos os códigos, fiz através de  websocket onde a aplicação desktop aguarda a requisição websocket para abrir, deu certo mais não gostei do resultado, websocket às vezes não recebe os bites completos.

Gostaria de uma solução como webservice, porem a requisição tem que partir com os parâmetros do browser, e assim abrir o windows form depois apos cadastrar a digital ou validar dar um callback para navegador novamente.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer a sua aplicação subir um serviço HTTP WCF na maquina local e chamar via javascript no localhost. Por exemplo, você sempre sobe o serviço em alguma porta especifica.
Exemplo:

http://localhost:8083/MeuServicoWCF